# return char* within a while loop

Tags: c

I am trying to print the contents of a linked list which is a char* but the while loops
are messing up the code:

the function to get the next item in a linked list:

```
char * list_next(list *l)
{
    list *currentPosition = NULL;
    currentPosition = l->next; //since the first node is a dummy value in the singly linked list

    while (currentPosition != NULL)
    {
        return currentPosition->charValue;
        currentPosition = currentPosition->next;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

in my main:

```
char * item;
while(item = list_next(list))
    printf("%s ",item);
```

can someone please help me I am pretty sure the problem is the returns inside the while 
loop but i cant seem to fix it

Comment: Please post a minimal program that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Why don't you use an `if` statement if you're returning in the *while* loop anyway? Another problem I see is that your list may start with a dummy value but you iterate over the whole list your main unit thus there will be only one dummy value.

Comment: What happens if l is passed in as NULL?  Bad things.  At least ASSERT that.

Comment: @ComFreek i cant just use a if statement because i have more than 1 node which has a char value. My question basically is how to return more than 1 char* in a method

Answer (score 3):

Swap the two lines. `return` immediately exits from the function. It should read

```
currentPosition = currentPosition->next;
return currentPosition->charValue;
```

instead.

(Not to mention numerous other errors that others pointed out as well - the lack of ability to actually update the `next` pointer because of confusion about scopes, the missing check for `NULL` before dereferencing, etc.)

Comment: I've just written a comment under the question which explains that the OP is making a *logic bug* here.

Comment: @ComFreek Yap. Maybe I should point it out - however, that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: the loop goes on forever with a single value from the list

Answer (score 2):

Your program, even with the return position swapped is still only going to print the "2nd" item in the list every time through - if it exists.  You either need to work with a double pointer to update the base value, or come up with some better way to iterate your list.

Comment: As this really feels like a homework question, I'm reluctant to put actual code here to solve it...

Comment: Therefore I've added some hints for the OP ;)

Comment: Umm, please don't add to my posts.  Edit is for grammar and formatting, not for adding ideas that I don't even agree with...

Comment: I'm **sorry** for my edit. You're right: this question is not a community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

You pass the original list to list_next().  I believe you will always print the second item in a forever loop.

I suggest you can simplify it as below:

```
char *item;
for (item=list->next; // Skip the first item as you said the first node is dummy.
     item != NULL; item=item->next) {
    printf("%s ",item->charValue);
}
```

Comment: doing a prinf in the list_next() method is not a problem the problem is that i need to return all the char values in the linked list

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned in a comment that you just need to return all values in the linked list.

```
function iterate(someNode)
   if someNode ≠ null
     node := someNode
     do
       do something with node.value [1]
       node := node.next
     while node ≠ someNode
```

<sub>From this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Linked_list_operations), [CC BY-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).</sub>

Now you could simply `printf()` at position [1] in the code. However it seems that you have to *return* all values.
Therefore you have to create an (probably dynamic) array.